# Using a std::vector<double> in call but getting an error about std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > being used

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector

I have a function that creates a vector, then calls a class constructor with that vector as an input, but it returns with an error saying

```
undefined reference to Class::Class(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >)
```

The class has a constructor for a

```
std::vector<double>
```

but not a

```
std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >
```

Some example code:

```
std::vector<double> x1;
std::vector<double> x2;
std::vector<double> myvec;
double thisX;

for (int i=0; i<x1.size(); i++ {
    thisX = x1[i];
    myvec.push_back(thisX);
}
for (int i=0; i<x2.size(); i++ {
    thisX = x2[i];
    myvec.push_back(thisX);
}

Class MyClass( myvec );
// has a constructor for std::vector<double>
// compiler throws the undefined reference to 
// Class::Class(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >)
```

Any insight is appreciated! I'm relatively new to C++ if it wasn't obvious.

Comment: The linker did not see the definition of your constructor that takes a `std::vector<double>`. And a `std::vector` is a *class-template* that has two template parameters. The element type, and an allocator type. the allocator is a default template parameter

Comment: take a look at some [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). A vector has always a second template parameter which defaults to `std::allocator<T>`

Comment: Where do you defined the constructor?

Comment: Those two are the same type, so your class can't have a constructor for `vector<double>`. The "undefined reference" indicates that you have declared one, but that it doesn't have an implementation. The two most common reasons for a missing implementation are 1) forgetting to write one, and 2) forgetting to link with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<double>` is the short form of `std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >`, because the second template argument of `std::vector<>` defaults to `std::allocator<T>`.

The cause of the error is different.

---

`undefined reference to Class::Class` error means that there is a *declaration* of this constructor but no *definition*.

You probably do not link the object file or library with the *definition* of `Class::Class`. It needs to be linked to resolve that undefined reference.

Comment: What if the class is defined in a `.h` file that lies in the same directory of my `.cpp` program?